# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toISOString')

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image]

```
import './ExpenseItem.css';

function ExpenseItem(props){

return (
    <div className="expense-item">
        <div>{props.date.toISOString()}</div>
        <div className="expense-item__description">
            <h2>{props.title}</h2>
            <div class="expense-item__price">${props.amount}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
)
}

export default ExpenseItem;
```

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toISOString')

Comment: date is undefined .  <div>{props.date && props.date.toISOString()}</div> use this

Comment: It is not trivial at the begging why date is null, because if you pass date.toISOString() it will work. So, check if you have a component without any prop ;)

Answer (score 3):

It will give this error because your `props.date` is `undefined` and you can not call `toISOString` in `undefined`.

So, please check why `props.date` field is `undefined`, and if the case is related to `API calling` or `asynchronous` then go with the `optional chaining` solution, or if it is not supported then go with the `regular` flow.

**Optional Chaining**

```
<div>{props.date?.toISOString()}</div>
```

**Regular**

```
<div>{props.date ? props.date.toISOString() : null}</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like either `props` or `props.date` is `undefined`. `undefined` does not have a method`toISOString`. Thus calling this function throws an error.

Make sure that you pass in correct props in your parent Component.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.
The problem was actually in the App.js file
I wrote the wrong syntax of ExpenseItem.
There fore you should check that you include the props in the ExpenseItem tag, not outside, not beetween!
Example <ExpenseItem "THE PROPS" >

```
<ExpenseItem
    title={expenses[0].title}
    amount={expenses[0].amount}
    date={expenses[0].date}
  ></ExpenseItem>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check opening and closing brackets(<>) where ExpenseItem component is imported in App.js
For example:
<ExpenseItem title="abc" amount="123" date={new Date(2021, 12, 15)}>

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error. The problem is in App.js file, in custom component attribute I forgot to pass date but I'm supposed to received in App.js hence it showing error.

Comment: would you be able to show a code sample of where that date is required?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32083967)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. It appeared that I forgot to write zero in square brackets in one of my attributes:

```
date={expenses[0].date}
```